# FormatFloat fmt param: b, e, E, f, g, etc

Tags: go

```
strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'E', -1, 64)
```

https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#FormatFloat

What does the `fmt` param exactly do? I just want as few decimals as possible. In this case I'm working with monetary amounts and want to convert the values into strings with 2 decimals (or as few as possible)

After reading the docs I guess I have to use either `g` or `G`. But what is the difference?

And what about the `prec` param? In the example it passes `-1`

Comment: "The format fmt is one of 'b' (-ddddp±ddd, a binary exponent), 'e' (-d.dddde±dd, a decimal exponent), 'E' (-d.ddddE±dd, a decimal exponent), 'f' (-ddd.dddd, no exponent), 'g' ('e' for large exponents, 'f' otherwise), 'G' ('E' for large exponents, 'f' otherwise), 'x' (-0xd.ddddp±ddd, a hexadecimal fraction and binary exponent), or 'X' (-0Xd.ddddP±ddd, a hexadecimal fraction and binary exponent)." - what's wrong with that explanation?

Comment: The next paragraph explains `prec`, also what `-1` means.

Comment: The difference between `G` and `g` is that `G` may use `E` or `f` and `g` may use `e` or `f`.

Answer (score 0):

> After reading the docs I guess I have to use either g or G. But what is the difference?

When the number is formatted using an exponent, `g` uses the character 'e' before the exponent and `G` uses the character 'E' before the exponent.

> And what about the prec param?

For the `g` and `G` formats, `prec` specifies  the maximum number of [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).  The special value -1 uses the minimum number of digits required roundtrip the number through format and parse.

> I'm working with monetary amounts

Floating point numbers are generally not a good choice when working with monetary amounts.